Explicit construction of integers with prescribed digit sum and residue class conditions
Let $q\geq 2$ be an integer, and $p,m\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $S_q$ be the function sum of digits in base $q$. If $\gcd(q-1,m)=1$, I was wondering if there is simple way to construct $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $S_q(kp)\equiv 1\mod{m}$?
Some context: If $\gcd(q-1,m)=1$, a result of Gelfond establishes that for every $b\in \mathbb{Z}_m$, the set $\{n:\ S_q(n)\equiv b\mod m\}$ is equally distributed in residue classes $\mod{p}$. In particular, there exist infinitely many integers such that $n\equiv 0\mod p$ and $S_q(n)\equiv 1\mod m$. I am interested in finding at least one, but without having to rely on exponential sums (which is Gelfond's proof).
I posted the question some days ago on the Mathematics StackExchange: you can see it by going to this link.

There is a grotesque but completely elementary construction. Let $p=gw$, where $(w,q)=1$ (and thus the last digit of $w$ is not $0$) and $g\mid q^M$. Let $N=q^M(q^{L\varphi(w)}+q^Rw-1)$, where $L>0$ is chosen so that $q^{L\varphi(w)}>q(q^Rw-1)$. Then $w\mid N$ by Euler theorem, $g\mid N$ (so, $p\mid N$, since $(g,w)=1$) and $S_q(N)=S_q(w)+(q-1)R$. There is $R$ such that $S_q(w)+(q-1)R\equiv 1\pmod m$, since $(q-1,m)=1$. Take such $R$, take large enough $L$, so $k=N/p\in\mathbb N$, and we are done.
